# Where to store VCS version in RPM?

Tags: git, rpm, vcs

We're using Git as our VCS and RPMs for packaging. I'd like to store the Git hash a package was built from, but I'm not sure on the most appropriate place.

There are a number of [tags](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html) available to an RPM, however I don't see any for a VCS version (maybe glanced over it?).

I'm quite leery about [adding a custom tag](http://rpm5.org/community/rpm-devel/4315.html), just looking at the 50,000 ft level.

One solution that feels pretty hacky would be to put the Git hash in the *description* field. We're not using it for anything else at this point, but wow, that just feels ugly.

So what is the most appropriate place to store a VCS version in an RPM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora (and very rarely RHEL) [place this information in the Release tag](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Versioning#Snapshots).

For instance:

```
Name:           mypackage
Version:        0.0.1
Release:        20140114git0abcdef
```

Comment: Currently I'm using the build number from Jenkins for the release tag, but it might make more sense to use the hash instead, or a combination thereof. It's nice to have both really, if at all possible. Thanks for your answer and the link, very helpful.

Comment: If you do more than one build per day, then throwing in the build number would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

RPM actually has a poorly documented `VCS` tag.

It doesn't appear to have any sort of guidelines on its use, but it exists and is supported.

```
cat > test.spec <<'__END__'
Name: foo
Version: 1
Summary: foo
License: None
Release: 1
VCS: git:repo=my-repo:branch=my-branch:sha=1234deadbeef

%description
foo
__END__


$ rpmspec -q test.spec --qf "%{VCS}\n"
git:repo=my-repo:branch=my-branch:sha=1234deadbeef
```

It appears to be limited to a single parse token. Still useful. I didn't find any documentation on a well defined format or structure for it, and its adoption is limited. On my Fedora 32 system I found two packages using it, with different formats:

```
$ rpm -qa --qf '%{Name} %{VCS}\n' |grep -v '(none)'
bcache-tools https://github.com/g2p/bcache-tools.git
libcue scm:git:https://github.com/lipnitsk/libcue.git
$
```

Frankly it's a real shame rpm doesn't give us the ability to inject custom tag info. I want to record the Jenkins build ID and job name, the git commit hash, and git branch or tag, but don't really want them in the changelog.

I can do this in debs with `X-BS-foo` tags.

---

You can see a list of allowed rpm tags with `rpm --querytags`.

The `DISTURL` tag appears to be [reserved for another use](https://saschpe.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/getting-the-sources-of-your-rpms/) but could be a candidate.

There's also `URL`; you could choose to embed SCM info there, and have a redirect that takes the URL to a reasonable location if visited by a browser.

---

You may see references to "rpm5" supporting custom tags. This seems to be a dead fork of rpm, not the rpm.org distribution used on most major distros.

Comment: Mad props for the follow up 6+ years later!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything will prevent you from storing all required information in a VERSION file in the docs directory. The path to that file could be added to the VCS tag (although I have not tested that).